# Allocating memory to this object in c++

Tags: c++, this

I have a class called `Node` which has two constructors. When I try to call one of the constructors from the other and assign it to the memory pointed by this of the caller I don't get any error. But when I try to assign memory/object allocated on heap using `new` to `this` I get an error **expression is not assignable**. Following is my code. What could be the possible reasons?

```
class Node{
    private:
       int key;
       Node* left, *right;
    public:
       Node(){
           left=NULL;
           right= NULL;
       }

       Node(int data){
           this=new Node(); // generates error 'expression is not assignable'
           *this= Node();   //compiles succesfully
           this->key=data;   
       }
}
```

Comment: Btw your second line (*this = Node();) is creating a temporary Node object, then using the compiler-provided default assignment operator (Node::operator=(const Node &)) to copy the temporary Node's state over to the first Node object's state, then destroying the temporary Node object.  That works, but I think you'll be better off avoiding that and just initializing the member values directly instead.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner *"you can't call one constructor from another constructor in C++"* -- You can in C++11.

Comment: @cdhowie right you are, I'd forgotten that :)

Comment: Nobody has commented that you are doing something really, really weird. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Dúthomhas I didn't want to initialize the same variables again rather use the constructor which had them initialized. Moreover, I am learning Object Oriented C++, so trying out things which I think are logical to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 allows [delegating constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class Node {
    private:
       int key;
       Node* left, right;

    public:
       Node() {
           left = NULL;
           right = NULL;
       }

       Node(int data) : Node() {
           this->key=data;   
       }
};
```

A few other comments about your code:

---

```
Node* left, right;
```

This declares `left` to be pointer-to-`Node` and `right` to be `Node` (not a pointer), as though you had written this:

```
Node* left;
Node right;
```

This is why you place the asterisk to the left of the variable, not the right of the type:

```
Node *left, *right;
```

Or, even better:

```
Node *left;
Node *right;
```

---

```
left = NULL;
```

In C++11, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.  You should be using an initializer list anyway:

```
Node() : left(nullptr), right(nullptr) { }
```

Comment: Sorry for the `Node* left, right` part. forgot one asterisk while writing the question. Learnt something new. Thank you :)